# PivotTable to show values, not sum of values

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2007, pivot-table

I'm wanting to display a pivot table and for it to show me the actual values, one on each row, rather than a sum of the values.  E.g.

```
Name    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr
Bob     12    10          4
        3     5      
James   2     6     8     1
                    15
```

etc.

My starting point is having three columns: `Name`, `Value` and `Month`.

Is this possible without having to do something completely different?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. A pivot table is a summary tool that performs calculations on a dataset

Comment: I was just using the word pivot table as I thought that was the right terminology, but possibly not!  My starting point is having 3 columns: Name, Value and Month.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As this is the first result for this question on Bing, a useful answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70051405/9074788

Comment: If there is only one value for each item in each month you can change the value function used from sum to max. I often do this to handle this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I fear this might turn out to BE the long way round but could depend on how big your data set is – presumably more than four months for example.

Assuming your data is in `ColumnA:C` and has column labels in Row 1, also that Month is formatted `mmm`(this last for ease of sorting):

1. Sort the data by Name then Month
2. Enter in `D2` `=IF(AND(A2=A1,C2=C1),D1+1,1)` (One way to deal with what is the tricky issue of multiple entries for the same person for the same month).
3. Create a pivot table from `A1:D(last occupied row no.)`
4. Say insert in `F1`.
5. Layout as in screenshot.

[image: SO12803305 example]

I’m hoping this would be adequate for your needs because pivot table should automatically update (provided range is appropriate) in response to additional data with refresh. If not (you hard taskmaster), continue but beware that the following steps would need to be repeated each time the source data changes.

5. Copy pivot table and Paste Special/Values to, say, `L1`.
6. Delete top row of copied range with shift cells up.
7. Insert new cell at `L1` and shift down.
8. Key 'Name' into `L1`.
9. Filter copied range and for `ColumnL`, select `Row Labels` and numeric values.
10. Delete contents of `L2:L(last selected cell)`
11. Delete blank rows in copied range with shift cells up (may best via adding a column that counts all 12 months).
    Hopefully result should be as highlighted in yellow.

Happy to explain further/try again (I've not really tested this) if does not suit.

**EDIT** (To avoid second block of steps above and facilitate updating for source data changes)

.0. Before first step 2. add a blank row at the very top and move `A2:D2`
    up.
 .2. Adjust cell references accordingly (in `D3` `=IF(AND(A3=A2,C3=C2),D2+1,1)`.
 .3. Create pivot table from `A:D`

.6. Overwrite `Row Labels` with `Name`.
.7. PivotTable Tools, Design, Report Layout, Show in Tabular Form and sort rows and columns A>Z.
.8. Hide `Row1`, `ColumnG` and rows and columns that show `(blank)`.

[image: additional example]

Steps .0. and .2. in the edit are not required if the pivot table is in a different sheet from the source data (recommended).

Step .3. in the edit is a change to simplify the consequences of expanding the source data set. However introduces `(blank)` into pivot table that if to be hidden may need adjustment on refresh. So may be better to adjust source data range each time that changes instead: PivotTable Tools, Options, Change Data Source, Change Data Source, Select a table or range). In which case copy rather than move in .0.

Comment: Yeah, it works for any number of Name and Month and because it's not checking the Value column, it doesn't matter if the value is repeated for the same month and the same name. I didn't do the rest either as I much prefer self-updating things but if it were to go into a presentation, I would definitely use the rest of it!

Answer (score 3):

Another easier way to do it is to upload your file to google sheets, then add a pivot, for the columns and rows select the same as you would with Excel, however, for values select Calculated Field and then in the formula type in =

[image: In my case the column header is URL]

Comment: This solution has potential, however i am concerned that the solution is not complete . is the formula just "=" ? -- doesnt work on my side

Comment: GOOGLE SHEETS SOLUTION: Yes, the above IS incomplete in the text of it, but the image is correct. In the Formula field, put **=(name of field to display in cells)**